# Arduino IDE 2.1.1 Mac M2 - Fails to upload, No drive to deploy, Raspberry Pico

Tags: arduino-ide, uploading, arduino-ide-2, raspberrypi-pico

I'm using Arduino IDE 2.1.1 on a Mac M2 and it's failing to upload, No drive to deploy, I have tried 3 different Mac's, and multiple Picos & USB cables.

Summary of what I've done:

- Loaded Example Blink application
- Selected board Raspberry Pico W from Raspberry Pi Pico Arduino core 3.3.2
- Port selection initially UF2 which shows connected and successfully uploads, then shows as /dev/cu.usbmodem1101

The first time I do the above the blink application works but any further uploads to /dev/cu.usbmodem1101 fail, with the following output:

```
Resetting /dev/cu.usbmodem1101
Converting to uf2, output size: 660992, start address: 0x2000
Scanning for RP2040 devices
No drive to deploy.
Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 1
```

I have only two ports available for upload

- /dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port
- /dev/cu.usbmodem1101

It feels as if I'm either consistently missing some key configuration details or there's technical issues with Arduino IDE or the Pico's

Comment: I am not sure if you have the same problem, but I am positive the [Arduino-Pico](https://github.com/earlephilhower/arduino-pico) core has some issues in the platform definition regarding the [pluggable discovery](https://arduino.github.io/arduino-cli/dev/pluggable-discovery-specification/), and the monitor does not work. See [arduino/arduino-ide#2100 (comment)](https://github.com/arduino/arduino-ide/issues/2100#issuecomment-1600799990) for more details. You can [start a discussion](https://github.com/earlephilhower/arduino-pico/discussions) and ask the platform maintainers. I hope this helps.